# addAsn1MibSource is not loading the mibs from git repo

Tags: python-2.7, snmp, pysnmp

```
>>> errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
...     getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
...            CommunityData('testing'),
...            UdpTransportTarget(('127.0.0.1', 17020)),
...            ContextData(),
...            ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('FSS-COMMON-SMI', 'fssCommon', '100.1.1.0').addAsn1MibSource('http://rtx-swtl-git.xyz.net.local/projects/TYREPO/repos/xyz_base_yang_repo/browse/src/util/snmp/@mib@')))
... )
```

**The path is a git repo path. what I am missing ?**

```
 raise error.MibNotFoundError('%s compilation error(s): %s' % (modName, errs))
pysnmp.smi.error.MibNotFoundError: FSS-COMMON-SMI compilation error(s): Illegal character '<', 21913 characters left unparsed at this stage at MIB FSS-COMMON-SMI, line 1
```

**If I perform the same by coping the mibs manually in the local and compile it with mibdump.py it works fine.**

```
python /local/python/2.7.8/bin/mibdump.py ./FSS-SYSTEM.mib

.....
Try various filenames while searching for MIB module: yes
Created/updated MIBs: FSS-SYSTEM
Pre-compiled MIBs borrowed:
Up to date MIBs: FSS-COMMON-SMI, SNMPv2-CONF, SNMPv2-SMI, SNMPv2-TC
Missing source MIBs:
Ignored MIBs:
Failed MIBs:
```

#

If copy all the bibs in from url path to local works fine:

```
{abc@cins}$ ls /data//users/sbhattac/MIBS/XYZ/
FSS-COMMON-LOG.mib  FSS-COMMON-SMI.mib  FSS-COMMON-TC.mib  FSS-SYSTEM.mib
```

if copy the same mibs in local works fine:

```
>>> from pysnmp.hlapi import *
>>> errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
...     getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
...            CommunityData('testing'),
...            UdpTransportTarget(('127.0.0.1', 17020)),
...            ContextData(),
...            ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('FSS-COMMON-SMI', 'fssCommon', '100.1.1.0').addAsn1MibSource('/data/users/sbhattac/MIBS/XYZ/', '/usr/share/snmp/')))
```

before:

```
ls
IPV6-TC.py  IPV6-TC.pyc
```

after:

```
{abc@cin}$ ls
FSS-COMMON-SMI.py  FSS-COMMON-SMI.pyc  IPV6-TC.py  IPV6-TC.pyc
```

As ilya suggested:

```
{abc@cin}$ python /local/python/2.7.8/bin/mibdump.py --rebuild --mib-source http://rtx-swtl-git.xyz.net.local/projects/TYREPO/repos/xyz_base_yang_repo/browse/src/util/snmp/@mib@ --mib-source /usr/share/snmp/ FSS-SYSTEM
Source MIB repositories: /usr/share/snmp/, http://rtx-swtl-git.xyz.net.local/projects/TYREPO/repos/fujitsu_base_yang_repo/browse/src/util/snmp/@mib@
Borrow missing/failed MIBs from: http://mibs.snmplabs.com/pysnmp/notexts/@mib@
Existing/compiled MIB locations: pysnmp.smi.mibs, pysnmp_mibs
Compiled MIBs destination directory: /home/sbhattac/.pysnmp/mibs
MIBs excluded from code generation: RFC-1212, RFC-1215, RFC1065-SMI, RFC1155-SMI, RFC1158-MIB, RFC1213-MIB, SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB, SNMP-TARGET-MIB, SNMPv2-CONF, SNMPv2-SMI, SNMPv2-TC, SNMPv2-TM, TRANSPORT-ADDRESS-MIB
MIBs to compile: FSS-SYSTEM
Destination format: pysnmp
Parser grammar cache directory: not used
Also compile all relevant MIBs: yes
Rebuild MIBs regardless of age: yes
Do not create/update MIBs: no
Byte-compile Python modules: yes (optimization level 0)
Ignore compilation errors: no
Generate OID->MIB index: no
Generate texts in MIBs: no
Try various filenames while searching for MIB module: yes
Created/updated MIBs:
Pre-compiled MIBs borrowed:
Up to date MIBs:
Missing source MIBs:
Ignored MIBs:
Failed MIBs: FSS-SYSTEM (Illegal character '<', 21893 characters left unparsed at this stage at MIB FSS-SYSTEM, line 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels like a MIB compilation error (FSS-COMMON-SMI) rather than a search path problem. Try it with `mibdump.py` like this:

```
$ mibdump.py --rebuild --mib-source http://rtx-swtl-git.xyz.net.local/projects/TYREPO/repos/xyz_base_yang_repo/browse/src/util/snmp/@mib@' --mib-source /usr/share/snmp/mibs FSS-SYSTEM
```

In your `mibdump.py` run, it has not re-compiled the `FSS-COMMON-SMI` MIB because it found the previously compiled one somehow.

Make sure you have a single version of these MIBs -- it may happen that the pysmi library uses different MIBs with different outcomes what makes it puzzling for you. You can enable pysmi debugging to `mibdump.py` and/or in pysnmp to see where it sources the MIBs from (e.g. `mibdump.py --debug reader,searcher ...`). The `--help` reveals more debugging options.

Comment: tried as you suggested getting error as : Failed MIBs: FSS-SYSTEM (Illegal character '<', 21893 characters left unparsed at this stage at MIB FSS-SYSTEM, line 1)

Comment: updated the same in the question. looks like there some problem while reading from the web url path.

Comment: Can it be a web server configuration problem? If you do a `wget` or `curl` for a MIB by that URL, will you get an ascii text document? I'm suspecting you are getting HTML what breaks parser.

Comment: Hi Ilya yes you are right its a git web server problem. Url containing browse path is not working but if I provide the "raw" file path its working like: "http://rtx-swtl-git.xyz.net.local/projects/TYREPO/repos/xyz_base_yang_repo/raw/src/util/snmp/@mib@" instead of : "http://rtx-swtl-git.xyz.net.local/projects/TYREPO/repos/xyz_base_yang_repo/browse/src/util/snmp/@mib@"

Answer (score 0):

for git repo raw file path need to be provided insted of browse path. Like
http://rtx-swtl-git.xyz.net.local/projects/TYREPO/repos/xyz_base_yang_repo/**raw**/src/util/snmp/@mib@